# Rename files using regex on linux using script

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I would like to rename the following files. Basically extracting the words to the left of the year, removing any non alphanumeric characters and replacing them with a space, then putting the year in parenthesis to the right.

```
Annabelle.2014.HC.HDRip.XViD.AC3-juggs[ETRG].avi
Dracula Untold 2014 720p HDRip x264 AC3-JYK.mkv
From.Paris.with.Love.2010.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4
Godzilla.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4
If.I.Stay.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264-SPARKS.mkv
Into.the.Storm.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4
Jessabelle.2014.HDRip.XViD-juggs[ETRG].avi
Ouija.2014.1080p.HC.WEBRip.x264.AAC2.0-RARBG.mp4
Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (2014) 1080p Full HDRip x264 AC3 6Ch-CPG.mp4
The.Purge.Anarchy.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4
Transformers.Age.of.Extinction.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4
```

So the output should look like:

```
Annabelle (2014).avi
Dracula Untold (2014).mkv
From Paris with Love (2010).mp4
Godzilla (2014).mp4
If I Stay (2014).mkv
Into the Storm (2014).mp4
Jessabelle (2014).avi
Ouija (2014).mp4
Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (2014).mp4
The Purge Anarchy (2014).mp4
Transformers Age of Extinction (2014).mp4
```

I learn by example, and I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I would show you what I've tried, but it's too embarrassing.

Comment: What would be the output if the input is `Dracula Untold 2014 720p HDRip x264 2014 AC3-JYK.mkv` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Dracula Untold (2014).mkv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
sed -r 'y/./ /; s/[()]//g; s/^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+).*\s([a-z0-9]+)$/\1(\2).\3/;' inputFile
```

Give output as

```
Annabelle (2014).avi
Dracula Untold (2014).mkv
From Paris with Love (2010).mp4
Godzilla (2014).mp4
If I Stay (2014).mkv
Into the Storm (2014).mp4
Jessabelle (2014).avi
Ouija (2014).mp4
Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles  (2014).mp4
The Purge Anarchy (2014).mp4
Transformers Age of Extinction (2014).mp4
```

**Usage**

```
for file in *
do
   mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -r 'y/./ /; s/[()]//g; s/^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+).*\s([a-z0-9]+)$/\1(\2).\3/;')"
done
```

**Test**

```
$ ls
Annabelle.2014.HC.HDRip.XViD.AC3-juggs[ETRG].avi  From.Paris.with.Love.2010.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4  Godzilla.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4
$ for file in *; do    mv $file "$(echo $file | s sed -r 'y/./ /; s/[()]//g; s/^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+).*\s([a-z0-9]+)$/\1(\2).\3/;' )" ; done
$ ls
Annabelle (2014).avi  From Paris with Love (2010).mp4  Godzilla (2014).mp4
```

Comment: WOW! That's really cool! How would I trigger the rename?

Comment: I get "mv: target `(2014).mp4' is not a directory" for every file in the directory.

Comment: It worked on all the files except two. "mv: target `Dracula Untold (2014).mkv' is not a directory
mv: target `Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles  (2014).mp4' is not a directory"

Comment: @DavidCuster edite the answer to correct that

Comment: Awesome! One last thing, I noticed an extra space on the file "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles  (2014).mp4". Is this fixable?

Comment: @DavidCuster yes it is fixable and the edited answer fixes that. Hope it is fine now :)

Comment: Yay! This is so awesome! Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @DavidCuster you are welcome :) glad i was of some help

Answer (score 1):

I tried your above code in perl program.

If necessary make use of it.

```
   use warnings;
   use strict;    
    opendir(DIR, "$ARGV[0]");
    my @file = grep{/\.[^\.]+$/i} readdir(DIR);
    close(DIR);     

    foreach my $songs (@file){
        my $song = $songs;
        $song =~ s{((?:(?!(?:\()?[0-9]{4}(?:\))?).)*)(?:\()?(2[0-9]{3})(?:\))?(.*?)(\.[^\.]+)$}{$1 ($2)$4}igm;

        $song =~ s{((?:(?!(?:\()?[0-9]{4}(?:\))?).)*(?:\()?2[0-9]{3}(?:\))?)(\.[^\.]+)$}{
            my $songname = $1;
            my $songtype = $2;
            $songname =~ s{\.}{ }igm;
            qq($songname$songtype)
        }isgem;

        rename("$ARGV[0]\\$songs", "$ARGV[0]\\$song") || die ( "Error in renaming" );

    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Annabelle  (2014).avi
Dracula Untold  (2014).mkv
From Paris with Love  (2010).mp4
Godzilla  (2014).mp4
If I Stay  (2014).mkv
Into the Storm  (2014).mp4
Jessabelle  (2014).avi
Ouija  (2014).mp4
Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles  (2014).mp4
The Purge Anarchy  (2014).mp4
Transformers Age of Extinction  (2014).mp4
```

Comment: How would I direct that to a folder?

Comment: @David Custer  You are getting this files from a folder right. And you have to rename the file names in the same folder or other output folder.

Comment: The files need to be renamed in the same folder.

Comment: I have Edited the code. Please check it. $ARGV[0] is the songs Directory. Pass by Argument.

Comment: Lol I've never used perl (DIR, "$ARGV[0]"); Where does the path go? Does it replace ARGV?

Comment: This is the Directory path (DIR, "$ARGV[0]");you can use as directly like "c:\tmp\songs"

Answer (score 0):

Try the below `rename` command on the directory on which the files you want to rename are stored.

```
rename 's/\b\d{4}\b\K.+(?=\.)//g;s/[^A-Za-z\d]+(?=.*?\.[^.]+$)/ /g;s/\b(\d{4})\./($1)./' *.*
```

**Example:**

```
$ ls
Annabelle.2014.HC.HDRip.XViD.AC3-juggs[ETRG].avi
Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (2014) 1080p Full HDRip x264 AC3 6Ch-CPG.mp4
Transformers.Age.of.Extinction.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4
$ rename 's/\b\d{4}\b\K.+(?=\.)//g;s/[^A-Za-z\d]+(?=.*?\.[^.]+$)/ /g;s/\b(\d{4})\./($1)./' -vn *.*
Annabelle.2014.HC.HDRip.XViD.AC3-juggs[ETRG].avi renamed as Annabelle (2014).avi
Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (2014) 1080p Full HDRip x264 AC3 6Ch-CPG.mp4 renamed as Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (2014).mp4
Transformers.Age.of.Extinction.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4 renamed as Transformers Age of Extinction (2014).mp4
```

Comment: The files did not rename. I ran that In the directory that the files are located. I am running root, this is a testing VM.

Comment: did you add `-vn` parameters? What's the console output?

Comment: There is no error message. For example I do ls then get file1 file1, then I do rename 's/\b\d{4}\b\K.+(?=\.)//g;s/[^A-Za-z\d]+(?=.*?\.[^.]+$)/ /g;s/\b(\d{4})\./($1)./' -vn \*.\* then ls again and same file1 file2.

Comment: could anyone would post the reason for downvote?

Comment: @DavidCuster remove the `-vn` parameters form your command.. I just added it for how rename works for these type of files. Most of the `rename` command won't support this feature.

Comment: I just tried it. No error message. But it doesn't rename the files.

Comment: I don't know why. But it works for me. I won't delete this right answer even if i get 10 or 20 downvotes without any proper explanation.

Comment: Weird. :( I'm still trying. I'll keep you updated. You've been really helpful!